# prove such that it satisfies property of being z inverse?

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that $\frac{\bar{z}}{{|z|}^2}$ satisfies the property of being $z$-inverse. That is, prove that
    $z^{-1} = \frac{\bar{z}}{{|z|}^2}$

Comment: Did you try multiplying $\bar z/|z|^2$ and $z$ together?

Comment: Can you prove that $z$ times its conjugate is $|z|^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for $\;z \in \mathbb C, \;z\neq 0,\;\; z^{-1}z = zz^{-1} = 1\tag{1},$

and we've shown in an earlier problem that $z^{-1}$ of $z$ satisfying $(1)$ is *unique.*

Recall also that $\;z\overline{z} = \overline z z = |z|^2\tag{2}$

Now, 
$$
\begin{align} z\cdot \frac {\overline z}{|z|^2} & = \underbrace{\frac {z\overline z}{|z|^2} = \frac{\overline z z}{|z|^2}} = \frac{\overline z}{|z|^2} \cdot z \\ \\
& \quad\quad= \frac {|z|^2}{|z|^2}\\ \\
&\quad\quad = 1
\end{align}
$$

Since $$z\cdot \frac {\overline z}{|z|^2} = \frac{\overline z}{|z|^2}\cdot z = 1 \tag{3}$$
then by the definition of an inverse element, it follows from $(1)$ and $(3)$ that $$ z^{-1} = \frac{\overline z}{|z|^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for any $0\neq z\in\Bbb C\,\,,\,\,z\bar z = |z|^2\,$